# Impossibly complex game discussed in the Hitchhikers' Guide series

Tags: the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy

In one of the Hitchhikers' Guide books, Douglas Adams has an aside about an impossibly complex sport. I remember nothing except that I believe higher dimensions are involved.

I originally posted that the game is not Brockian Ultra-Cricket but upon review of the source material, I think that it is. I would delete this question but StackExchange does not let me.

Comment: The complex game you're describing is Brockian Ultra Cricket.

Comment: I suggest you post an answer to this question clarifying that it's Brockian Ultra Cricket, and mark it as accepted. This shows any future viewers that you consider this the correct answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per the comment by @Valorum, I believe I was thinking of Brockian Ultra Cricket, in particular the phrase

> a complete list of rules has only ever been assembled once (and the
>   book containing the assembled rules promptly collapsed into a black
>   hole)

Answer (score 8):

[Ford Prefect] “I read of one planet off in the seventh dimension that got used as a ball in a game of intergalactic bar billiards. Got potted straight into a black hole. Killed ten billion people.”

“That’s mad,” said Mella.

“Yes, only scored thirty points too.”

The Restaurant at the End of the Universe, Douglas Adams © 1980

Comment: Could you provide a citation for this quote?

Comment: They are the last words spoken in Episode 6 of the radio series between Ford and Arthur.